# Constraining the amount of movement on an axis in layout view

Tags: transforms, constraints, axis

I have a design where a part can slide on a rod that is aligned with the X axis. I need to move the part around to see how it looks in different positions on the rod. To make this easier, I have locked the Y and Z location transforms, so I can just press G and move the part around on the X axis. However, I don't want to be able to slide it off the rod, so I'd like the part's X position to be locked between, say, 0 and 70.

I know this is possible in animation but I'm not doing any animation here, I just need to move the part occasionally to check the esthetics but I don't want to be able to drag it too far along the axis.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Add a Limit Distance Object Constraint? You could add an empty and use that as the target. Use two constraints with one Clamp Distance set to Inside and one to Outside if you want to restrain to a minimum and maximum distance.

Comment: @JohnEason: why not writing an answer as that?

Comment: @Chris Will do! - I didn't have time yesterday. Maybe later today...